# Recalling function values in prompt text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope you'll forgive me if I have no clue what I'm saying as I've had no real instruction on how to write code. However, I will do my best to explain it well if you will bear with me.

Moving forward, I'm looking to create a prompt that appears upon opening a Google Sheet that will display both a line of text and a line of character values from a function. I may be doing this the most difficult way possible but this is all I have so far:

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Text goes here' return function lookup(today(),A1:B6));

I'm sure this looks like utter nonsense, but that's why I'm here! I need to be able to recall the contains of the first cell within a row that contains today's date. That is, if a sheet looks something like this:

ABC   3/21   3/28   4/1   4/4   4/7

DEF   3/20   3/29   4/2   4/5   4/9

I need it to read "Text goes here ABC" on the 4th of April and "Text goes here DEF" on the 5th of April.

I hope that makes sense. Please let me know if you need additional information! And I appreciate any help that is offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question. So first of all, I would recommend you check out `Browser.msgBox()` ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox%28String%29)).

So this isn't super easy, so it may take some work to understand what's going on here. But I [created a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rH64mYTJf47aJBsDMYwzj_sYkM9CKre9WBTBG4CfliA/edit#gid=0) that works for this. Here's the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  // get the values from the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  vals = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  // get a greeting based on the date
  var greeting = greetingsForDate(vals, formatDate(new Date()));

  // display the greeting
  Browser.msgBox("Text goes here " + greeting)
}

function greetingsForDate(vals, dateString) {
  var greetings = []

  // loop through each row
  for(var rowNum = 0; rowNum < vals.length; rowNum++) {
    rowContent = vals[rowNum];

    // loop through each column
    for(var columnNum = 1; columnNum < rowContent.length; columnNum++) {
      var cellVal = rowContent[columnNum];

      // return the value from column A if the current date is in the row
      if(typeof cellVal === "object" && formatDate(cellVal) === dateString) {
        greetings.push(rowContent[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  if(greetings.length === 0) {
    return "(none)";
  } else {
    return greetings.join(", ");
  }
}


// returns a formatted date like 04/02/14
function formatDate(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/d/y");
}
```

It assumes the sheet is structured like this:

```
ABC 3/21/2014   3/28/2014   4/1/2014    4/4/2014    4/7/2014
DEF 3/20/2014   3/29/2014   4/2/2014    4/5/2014    4/9/2014
```

If this code doesn't make whole lot of sense, I would highly recommend checking out a site like [codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com/) or [codeschool.com](https://www.codeschool.com/). Codecademy's [JavaScript course](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) is especially good.

Good luck!

**EDITS** to return multiple values and check that cells are dates as per the comments.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at what you recommended. I've been playing around with the code you gave me and I should have mentioned that I needed the message box to return both ABC and DEF (preferably with a comma and a space in between the two) if the rows they are in contain today's date. Is that an easy fix?

Comment: Ok! So you're saying that if both rows contain todays date, it would return `ABC, DEF`? If so, that's easy enough - I'll update the code. Also, be sure to mark as accepted answer if it works for you :).

Comment: Ok! No problem. I'll throw up that code later today.

Comment: @user3491710 there you are :) Notice the `return greetings.join()` and `greetings.push()` - it's building an array now instead of returning the first matching value it finds.

Comment: Neat. But when I use this code on my actual spreadsheet it keeps returning the error: Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string). (line 38, file "Code") Do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: Ah - so probably the reason was that one of the cells on your sheet (not column 1) had text in it other than a `date` (even `" "`), and then the code was trying to convert `text` to a `date`, which was throwing an error. So I added a check that the cell is a date first before trying to convert it to a date: `if(typeof cellVal === "object"`

Comment: That worked! Sorry to keep bugging you about this but if you don't mind, two more things came up :/ First, it's returning rows with today's _and_ tomorrow's date. And second, it would be nice if it overlooked the first column of dates (column B). I hope I'm not asking too much; you've done quite a lot already!

Comment: I figured out how to have the code overlook the first column! I'm getting the hang of this. Maybe now I can figure out how to have it not return tomorrow's date as well.

Comment: I misunderstood the issue: it's returning the date as tomorrow instead of today.

Comment: So if it's consistently returning tomorrow's date (and mostly matches the code that I posted), my bet would be that it's a timezone thing. Try running this function by itself: `function test() {   Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/d/y")); }`

If that gives the wrong date (open up the logger to check), then try changing the spreadsheet's timezone.

Comment: Also, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860477/utilities-formatdate-date-not-set-correct). I believe it may be close to what's causing your problem :)

Comment: The time zone was correct and that function returned the right date. I changed the timezone to "GMT-5" and it worked. Which is weird because I live in GMT-6 so I'm guessing it's an issue with daylight saving time. At any rate it's working perfectly now! Let's hope that doesn't change. Thanks for all of your help, I'm really grateful.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. This sounds right - and likely won't change. If it does, we can go a different route and compare the dates the official way, like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3ZYb/). Otherwise, good luck!