# Utilities.formatDate Date not set correct

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a date stored as follows:

```
existingDate = Wed Apr 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

When I use `Utilities.formatDate` to format the date the date is changed to the day before.

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(existingDate), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

the formatted date is then set to `29/04/2014` and **not** `30/04/2014`.

Has anyone else seen this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Utilities.formatDate` seems to be working fine.

You have Apr 30 midnight in **GMT-1** but then you tell it to format this date in a different timezone **GMT**, or more explicity GMT-0. The expected result is indeed Apr 29 23h.

The second parameter in [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate%28Date,String,String%29) must be the timezone you desire.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other issues with this google script.
If I want the timezone AEST but only have the date in the form of 1/27/2017, then Utilities.formatDate("1/27/2017","AEST","yyyy-MM-dd") will return a value of 2017-01-26, a day before it should be!  However if I have a time with it such as "1/27/2017 12:00:00" then it returns the correct day.  However if I use "GMT+11" as the timezone even without a time on the end if returns the correct day.

Example -

`Logger.log('Example 1='+Utilities.formatDate(new Date("1/27/2017"),"AEST","yyyy-MM-dd"));
Logger.log('Example 2='+Utilities.formatDate(new Date("1/27/2017 12:00:00"),"AEST","yyyy-MM-dd"));
Logger.log('Example 3='+Utilities.formatDate(new Date("1/27/2017"),"GMT+11","yyyy-MM-dd"));`

Output -

Example 1=2017-01-26

Example 2=2017-01-27

Example 3=2017-01-27

A workaround when reading a date from a spreadsheet cell that does not have a time is to add a time and when using a timezone like "AEST" or similar, something like this -

```
var displayDate = sheet.getRange(a1Notation).getDisplayValue();  // Not .getValue();
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(displayDate + " 12:00:00"), "AEST", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

However "GMT+11" would be easier because you don't need to add a time.

Comment: Even if I have all the correct timezones set in all related files, triple checked, I still get wrong dates as a result, when copying dates from sheets to docs. Driving me nuts. And times (durations) are totally wrong, off by something like 30 or 40 minutes. Nuts.